# How to fetch CoreData value specified?

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I set a CoreData entity with three attributes "name""sex""job"

I stored 5 data in it and want to use them to compare their job.
(each data contain "name""sex""job")

I know how to fetch them all in order(order by insert time ),but I don't know how to fetch only one of them?

ex: how to only fetch the first and the third insert data to check his job 
(like the following ,I want to find the first one Sue's job and the third one Ken's job ,others I don't care)

===========================

name:  Sue /  Bob / Ken / Lily / John

sex:   W / M / M / W / M

job: Manager / Staff / Staff / Staff / Assistant Manager

==========================================

please give me some advice or sample code ~

thank you ～

Comment: Order based on what? Why would you want to fetch the 3rd item only? It sounds like you might be approaching this problem wrongly, please try to explain more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: What criteria that will produce the data that you wish to get?  (can't just say third data!)

Comment: So sorry for my poor English ,I try to explain my question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fetch request offset property:

`[request setFetchOffset:3]`

for this to be the only object returned add:

`[request setFetchLimit:1]`

**Edit: (after question refinement)**

You cannot access your data by index for more then one object (unless they are consecutive in the order you define).

You need a way (key) to identify only the objects you need (if your name property is unique/key you could use it in this case). You could always use the managed object ID to uniquely identify a managed object

If you have the object IDs for the objects you are interested in, then just fetch them by using a predicate like: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@",objectIDs]`.
If you identify your objects by another key, define a predicate that will fetch you these items only ex.:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@",@[@"Sue",@"Ken"]]`
You could add a property marking the objects you need (BOOL property) and define your predicate with it.

If you have a small number of objects, there is no real problem in fetching all of them and just selecting the ones you need. If you have many objects, accessing them by index and not by key is probably not the way to go.

If you need to access these item because the user selected them, instead of saving their indices, save their object IDs and the access them by it.

Comment: OK! I got it thank you~